# Infinite scroll jquery plugin didn't work

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, jquery-plugins, pagination, jquery-infinite-scroll

I am trying to add infinite scrolling to codeigniter's pagination with the [Infinite scroll jquery plugin](http://www.infinite-scroll.com). But with no success

Here is my controller:

```
$config['base_url'] = site_url('news/home/');
$config['total_rows'] = $this->home_model->count_new();
$config['per_page'] = 3;
$config['uri_segment'] = 3;
$config['limit'] = $config['per_page'];
$this->pagination->initialize($config);
$data['news'] = $this->home_model->list_data_new($config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment($config['uri_segment']));
$this->load->view('news_view',$data);
```

Here is my view :

```
<div id="content">
<?php foreach ($news as $data):?>
    <?php echo $data['title']?>
    Post by: <?php echo $data['username']?>
<?php endforeach;?>
</div>
<button id="next">load more</button>
```

And here is the javascript also in view:

```
 $('#content').infinitescroll({
     navSelector  : "#next:last",            
     // selector for the paged navigation (it will be hidden)
     nextSelector : "#next:last",    
     // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
     itemSelector : "#content"          
     // selector for all items you'll retrieve
});
```

The pagination link will look like this `http://localhost/latihan/news/home/3` then click next will be like this `http://localhost/latihan/news/home/6`

The problem is the next post doesn't showing up and load more button is not loading data.

Any answer?

Many thanks...

Comment: What happens when you call the URLs of the pagination manually in the browser? Does ``http://localhost/latihan/news/home/6`` work at all?

Comment: yes it's work successfully

Answer (score 0):

Your setup is wrong.

I advise you have a look at the source code of the page http://www.infinite-scroll.com itself, because they are using their own plugin. Scroll down on the page to see it working.

Other than that I have to say that their product is extremely badly documented and works in quite unintuitive ways. For example, it will read the URL for the next page from `nextSelector`, but **only** when that element is a hyperlink `<a ...>` and **only** the first time. It will then parse that URL for occurrences of the number "2", load, and replace the number with 3 and so on. So your intended design with page 2 being home/3 and page 3 being home/6 will not work with this plugin.

**Do yourself a favor and use [jScroll](http://jscroll.com/) instead.**